# elasticdump How do I use offset?

Tags: elasticsearch

When elasticdump is stopped and restarted, it tries to execute after offset.
but an error occurs.

[Execute command]

```
nohup ./elasticdump --input=http://host/common --output=http://host/common --type=data --limit=1000 --offset=1000 &
```

[error]

> Error Emitted =>
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation
>   Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll
>   context;"}],"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation
>   Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll
>   context;"},"status":400}

How do I use offset???

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: The ES version in use is 6.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the notes in the [elasticdump project](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump#notes):

> if you are using Elasticsearch version 6.0.0 or higher the offset parameter is no longer allowed in the scrollContext

What you can do to prevent this (as long as you don't cross the [10000 limit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-request-from-size.html)) is to not use the `offset` parameter (i.e. no scroll context) and provide a search body instead with `from` and `size` settings, like this:

```
nohup ./elasticdump --input=http://host/common --output=http://host/common --type=data --searchBody='{"from": 1000, "size": 1000, "query": { "match_all": {} }}' &
```

**UPDATE:**

If you have more than 10K records and elasticdump is prone to stop midway, I suggest leveraging the [snapshot/restore feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) in order to move the data from one server to another.

Comment: But.. The total amount of data is more than 10,000. It is about 10 million.

Comment: Ok, but what are you trying to achieve? what is your use case with elastic dump? why do you want to extract only parts of your data?

Comment: I want to move all the data from one server to another.

Comment: In that case, why do you need the offset parameter at all? simply let it run from 0 to N

Comment: This is because when the "elasticdump" stops, it is read again from the beginning after it is executed again.

Comment: Why does it stop in the first place?

Comment: The elasticdump process terminates when an exception occurs, such as a server reboot or network outage. Also, when you run it again, you have to read the data from the beginning again...

Comment: In this case, I suggest another less cumbersome approach: [snapshot and restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html)

Comment: thankyou!! Is the snapshot and restore feature easy to move data to another server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use --limit parameter in the command, offset is dangerous to use as it can skip n number of records, n being the offset.

more reference - https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump

e.g.

```
elasticdump --input=domain/index --output "s3://bucket/file.json" --limit 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select  Elasticsearch  max id , and use searchBody continue dump.

elasticdump --input=http://host/common --output=http://host/common --type=data --searchBody='{"query": {"range": {"xxxId": {"gt": 10000}}}}' --limit=1000

Comment: Please learn to use code markup on this site, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help